# Internet Explorer memory leaks

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, internet-explorer-11

I have a webapp written in react that sends ajax requests to receive chunks of 5 pages of a document. For this the request itself calls its function recursively as a timeout to receive the next 5 pages.

Additional info: I use the official flux from the npm repositories.
Following code example:

```
function getPages() {

    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            var resp = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            SwitchViewAction.addPages(resp); // calls another setTimeout later,
                                             // because of react lifecycle

            if (Object.keys(resp).length > 0) {
                setTimeout(getPages(), 0);
            }
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("GET", '/GetDocumentPages/', true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

The problem is, that IE 11 allocates nearly ~20MB memory for each request (or timeout?). If I render a document with ~250 pages, IE runs out of memory and I get the following error:

```
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
```

I found  [this page](http://javascript.info/tutorial/memory-leaks), that explains that setTimeout sets an internal reference so the timeout is never deleted. But only for IE <9. So in 11 this problem should not be.

Chrome handles this perfectly. The maximum amount of memory usage is ~170MB for this huge document. IE runs over 1GB and returns the above error on the console. Later in the code I add "resp" to an array. If I do not add it, IE stays at ~220MB memory usage. So imho there must be a reference problem.

Further information: The document pages are sent as base64. I calculated the maximum size, when all pages are received. It is ~162MB for the document with 249 pages.

Is this a problem with IE handling the references, is it IE to not free memory, or am I on a completely wrong track? So what could it be then?

Comment: read this first: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250448(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The timeout syntax is not correct, you should call it like this:

```
setTimeout(getPages, 0);
```

Otherwise you call the function right away, and indeed would run out of memory as the state of previous function calls never get garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for that, but unfortunately that didn't help. For now it seems react to be the problem. When it renders, the memory explodes. Other browsers such as chrome and firefox can handle it. I'm going on searching.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that IE wastes memory while rendering base64 strings as images. The solution for me is to render only a bunch of pages and not the entire document.